# Robo 3T: Populate actual values of Javascript functions calls while Exporting Collections to JSON

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am very new to Mongo and have a requirement to export collection to JSON. I ran the below code to export to JSON and it worked fine. But main issue is there are some functions for which the value is different in Robo3T GUI in comparison to what is exported.

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('foo').find({}, {});
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    print(tojson(cursor.next()))
}
```

But main issue is there are some functions for which the value is different in Robo3T GUI in comparison to what is exported.
Ex: 
"_id" : BinData(3,"u9LO8nOI6UmsYJUin/DH8w==") is what is exported to JSON , while in GUI it is ("f2ced2bb-8873-49e9-ac60-95229ff0c7f3").

I want to export the values exactly what is seen on the Robo3T GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after all the research got the answer. Posting it below so that others facing the same issue can leverage.
The Bindata format is BSON and the one which is visible from mongo shell is in the form of hexadecimal as NUUID, CSUUID, PYUUID or something else.
I wanted to basically convert the BinData to NUUID format.
Run the below two functions on your console:

```
   function Base64ToHex(base64) {
        var base64Digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        var hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";
        var hex = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 24; ) {
            var e1 = base64Digits.indexOf(base64[i++]);
            var e2 = base64Digits.indexOf(base64[i++]);
            var e3 = base64Digits.indexOf(base64[i++]);
            var e4 = base64Digits.indexOf(base64[i++]);
            var c1 = (e1 << 2) | (e2 >> 4);
            var c2 = ((e2 & 15) << 4) | (e3 >> 2);
            var c3 = ((e3 & 3) << 6) | e4;
            hex += hexDigits[c1 >> 4];
            hex += hexDigits[c1 & 15];
            if (e3 != 64) {
                hex += hexDigits[c2 >> 4];
                hex += hexDigits[c2 & 15];
            }
            if (e4 != 64) {
                hex += hexDigits[c3 >> 4];
                hex += hexDigits[c3 & 15];
            }
        }
        return hex;
    }

BinData.prototype.toNUUID = function () {
    var hex = Base64ToHex(this.base64()); // don't use BinData's hex function because it has bugs in older versions of the shell
    var a = hex.substr(6, 2) + hex.substr(4, 2) + hex.substr(2, 2) + hex.substr(0, 2);
    var b = hex.substr(10, 2) + hex.substr(8, 2);
    var c = hex.substr(14, 2) + hex.substr(12, 2);
    var d = hex.substr(16, 16);
    hex = a + b + c + d;
    var uuid = hex.substr(0, 8) + '-' + hex.substr(8, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(12, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(16, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(20, 12);
    return uuid;
}
```

and then call the function in your extraction as below:

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('collectionname').find({});
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
var b=cursor.next()
b._id=b._id.toNUUID()
    print(tojson(b))
}
```

This will extract the data in the desired NUUID format or the column in JSON.